# Wordpress in subfolder of MEAN Stack

Tags: wordpress, mean-stack

I am developing a website on MEAN Stack but with this my requirement is to run a wordpress blog in a subfolder like URL structure. Can you recommend me the right way to do it.

URLs should look like

```
http://mywebsite.com/about-us (Served from MEAN)
http://mywebiste.com/product-catalogue (Served from MEAN)
http://mywebsite.com/blog (Served from Wordpress blog)
http://mywebsite.com/blog/* (Served from Wordpress blog)
```

Comment: Look into URL forwarding/redirect/masking. https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/77/how-do-i-set-up-url-forwarding-for-a-domain  
https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name-422

Comment: Is it even possible to make Apache (or Nginx) and Node.js listen to the same port at the same time for the same domain?

Comment: Does Node/Express allow proxying requests to other locations? Perhaps proxy `^blog/.*` to a secondary port where Apache is running e.g. `127.0.0.1:8080`? Or maybe use Nginx or something as a reverse proxy that splits traffic between MEAN and WP ports?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking of but dont know how to do it. Need help in this.

Comment: There are loads of tutorials available for setting up Nginx as a reverse proxy.

Comment: Did you get answer to this? I am finding the solution for same issue now.

Answer (score -1):

You should buy the `mywebsite.com` domain name, and then follow the specific instructions from your hosting provider to set up the required redirections to your MEAN site and your WP site.
That's the simplest way.

[GoDaddy - Manually forwarding or masking your domain name](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name-422)
[NameCheap - How do I set up URL forwarding for a domain?](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/77/how-do-i-set-up-url-forwarding-for-a-domain)

Comment: I guess I should have written my question other way. The actual issue not with hosting rather the technology. WP runs on PHP and MEAN on Node. How to couple them in such a way that I can achieve above mentioned URL results.

Comment: It doesn't matter what they run on. You can use <blogname>.wordpress.org, <meanwebsite>.com. Use URL forwarding from mywebsite.com to achieve the URL structure you require. I didn't say anything about hosting.

Comment: I am not getting your point.  http://mywesibte.com/about-us is being served by MEAN then how can http://mywebsite.com/blog can be served by WP. My WP should be installed on my on server and my browser URLs should not change.

Comment: [mywebsite.com/about-us] can forward/mask another URL, [mean.com]. [mywebsite.com/blog] can forward/mask to [wordpress.com]. Address bar will always show [mywebsite.com]. Read the links about URL forwarding/redirecting/masking. From the GoDaddy link: "Domain name forwarding lets you automatically direct your domain name's visitors to a different website.
Masking prevents visitors from seeing your domain name forwarding by keeping your domain name in the Web browser's address bar."